# Overflow issue in C#

Tags: c#

My error is:

> cs1501 No overload for method 'Write' takes 2 arguments

Here is the program itself. The error takes place on the writer.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    const string fileName = "Primes12345678910.txt";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int c = 1;
        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
        int olda = 1;
        int oldb = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            if (a * b == 1)
            {
                a = a + 1;
            }

            if (a * b == c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not prime.", c);
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new             BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    writer.Write("{0}", c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use writer.Write(string.Format("{0}", c));

Comment: There is no `BinaryWriter.Write` method which takes a string and an object. You may be looking for `StreamWriter`, which does have such a method.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to implement here? I'm not sure if this code is incomplete but even if it **did** compile it still wouldn't do much.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`BinaryWriter.Write(int value)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24e33k1w(v=vs.110).aspx) only takes one argument, so remove `{0}`, this is what it should look like:

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
{
    writer.Write(c);

    // Unless you want 'c' to be a string, then use
    writer.Write(c.ToString());

    // You can also use StringFormat
    writer.Write(string.Format("{0}", c));
}
```

Another option would be what @ScottChamberlain suggested, using a [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) as it supports what you are trying to do, [`StreamWriter.Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxhes7h2(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
{
    writer.Write("{0}", c);
}
```

Comment: That is going to have very diffrent behavior depending on what the type of `c` is, for because if it was a `int` of `1` it would write `0x00000001`. If you want the same behavior you would have to do `writer.Write(c.ToString())` which would write `0x000139` because it writes the length prefix using two bytes then it writes the UTF-16 value of the string `1` which is `0x39`. however looking at the code I think the op just just use a `StreamWriter` as they are just trying to write the list of primes to a file, also the file is opened in create mode he and you are both overwriting it every loop.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain c is an int. And BinaryWriter has support for an integer argument. Thank you for your comment, I have added `StreamWriter` to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at the compile error:

```
No overload for method 'Write' takes 2 arguments
```

In this case, it means exactly what it says: the `Write` method doesn't take two arguments.

As other people have indicated, the problem is here:

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new             BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
{
    writer.Write("{0}", c);
}
```

You either want to do

```
writer.Write(c.ToString());
```

as @BogDoeJoe suggested or, if you intended to use a format string, do

```
writer.Write(string.Format("{0}", c));
```

In this case a format string's rather pointless though.

Also, just as a quick note, I'm not sure if this code is incomplete but it won't actually do much right now. All it'll actually do is set `a` to 2 on the first iteration of the loop; after that it'll quite literally do nothing because `a * b = 2` and `c = 1` (so neither of your `if` statements can possibly be true ever again after the first iteration, and you'll never actually write anything to the console).

Comment: Thank you and yes it is unfinished this is just something I made in a few minutes.